# What's the deadline? A short answer

Tags: ellipsis, answers

Is the following question-response pair natural?

> A: What's the deadline?
>
> B: By May 3rd.

I know "by" is redundant, but redundancy does not mean unnaturalness.
Is the reply natural with it?

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely (and most idiomatic) response to "What's the deadline?" is the deadline expressed as a date or date/time, not the prepositional phrase, "by {deadline}".  But **by** is not *redundant* there. Rather, you're answering a question other than the one that was asked. The two questions might be practically the same, but they're not the same syntactically.

If you ask "When does this have to be submitted by?" then "by May 3rd" would answer the question.  You can omit **by**, and answer simply "May 3rd".

What **is** the deadline?
-- <strike>By</strike> May 3rd [is the deadline].

Comment: The one other case I can think of where including the _by_ would sound natural is in a full sentence; for example: Q: _When is the deadline?_ A: _We need to have this done **by** May 3rd._

Comment: Can I drop "by" in "When does this have to be submitted by?" and answer "By May 3rd"?

Comment: If you drop **by** in that question (*When does this have to be submitted?*), it could be taken to mean "on which date", not "by which date".  It is asking for a date of submission, not a deadline.

Comment: Why is anyone arguing with this answer? It's true, the OP's question would not be answered using the word by. However, it could be worded so it does use the word by. A deadline **is** some date; a thing has to be submitted **by some date**.

Comment: Both of you are right. It is ambiguous whether or not that day is the last day allowed for submission, or the first day on which it's too late!

Comment: @Lambie - Is someone arguing with this answer? I can't find any arguments.